# Update iOS App without waiting for submission

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, webview, app-store

I've seen solutions like AppHub that allow changes to an already-published iOS App without submitting an updated version to the App Store but as far as I know it doesn't support Xcode. Are there any others that are similar to AppHub that support AppCode and Swift?

My reason behind this is that I am making an app for my school and don't like using WebView. There is an announcements tab that needs to be updated daily but to submit an update to the App Store takes a couple of days.

Comment: Use a server or BAAS to push announcements. No need to wait for submission. You only need to do that if you are making UI or data model changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding daily news to your app, putting a new version on the App Store every day is definitely not the way to go. Look into a backend service like Firebase or AWS to deliver content updates without the need for the user to update the app daily to see them.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about Firebase. My only issue is that I can't format each announcement as it won't start a new line (It continues on one line then when out of room puts '...'). Is there any way I could fix this? (Image for ref: http://i.imgur.com/Eqd2ZGQ.png)