# How can I display data from Firebase in a Table View Controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, webview

I've been looking everywhere for a solution to this, but how can I display data from my Firebase database into a Table View Controller in Xcode?

What I'm trying to accomplish is for the main page of the app that will display news articles in each cell. Clicking on a cell will bring up the full article.

Would this be possible? If there is a better way to do this other than WebView, let me know.

Comment: The first hit on Googling "swift firebase tutorial" is http://www.raywenderlich.com/109706/firebase-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Thanks for this, but I've already seen this and isn't quite what I am looking for. What I was planning on doing is editing data from FireBase so it is instantly updated on the page without needing to be resubmitted to the App Store. My original post looking a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530612/update-ios-app-without-waiting-for-submission?noredirect=1#comment58750797_35530612

Comment: You need to explain your question further. The tutorial shows how you can access a Firebase database and display results in a table view. Are you asking how to then display the detail in a WebView? As always with StackOverflow, you should post the code that you've got, and describe the problem you're having with it. If you're just asking if it's a good idea to display a news article in a WebView, then some people might close your question because it is too broad, but yes, that's about your only choice if the news article contains HTML.